# Avoid Boolean as parameter for constructor | Complex Number Calculator

Tags: vb.net

I have written a class in VB.NET that has the task of applying various arithmetic operations to two complex numbers. The class can also determine the magnitude and phase of a complex number. The project is just an exercise, but I want to make it as good as possible.

For each calculation, 3 strings are created for output – as rectangular form, as trigonometric form and as polar form. The method "SetOutputStrings" needs the methods "AbsoluteValue" and "AngleInRad" for this, for which I need new instances of ComplexNumber. I need to pass a Boolean to avoid an overflow. Outside, in FormMain, I need to pass ‘False’ if I simply want to create two complex numbers that will be used in the respective method, and to avoid creating unnecessary OutputStrings. To be precise, I don't want to have to have a Boolean as a parameter for the constructor. Can you guys get this to work more elegantly?

Visual Studio 2019, WinForms application

**Class ComplexNumber.vb**

```
Friend NotInheritable Class ComplexNumber
    Private _Real As Double
    Private _Imag As Double
    Private _Output_Rectangular_form As String
    Private _Output_Exponential_form As String
    Private _Output_Trigonometric_form As String

    Friend Property Output_Rectangular_form As String ' 3+4⋅i
        Get
            Return _Output_Rectangular_form
        End Get
        Private Set
            _Output_Rectangular_form = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Property Output_Trigonometric_form As String ' r⋅(cos(ϕ)+i⋅sin(ϕ))
        Get
            Return _Output_Trigonometric_form
        End Get
        Private Set
            _Output_Trigonometric_form = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Property Output_Exponential_form As String ' r⋅e^(i⋅ϕ)
        Get
            Return _Output_Exponential_form
        End Get
        Private Set
            _Output_Exponential_form = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Property Real As Double
        Get
            Return _Real
        End Get
        Private Set
            _Real = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Property Imag As Double
        Get
            Return _Imag
        End Get
        Private Set
            _Imag = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Sub New(real As Double, imag As Double, setOutput As Boolean)
        Me.Real = real
        Me.Imag = imag
        If setOutput Then
            SetOutputStrings(real, imag)
        End If
    End Sub

    Friend Shared Function AbsoluteValue(v As ComplexNumber) As Double
        Return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(v.Real, 2.0) + Math.Pow(v.Imag, 2.0))
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function AngleInDegrees(v As ComplexNumber) As Double
        Dim phase As Double = Math.Atan(v.Imag / v.Real)

        If v.Real >= 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag >= 0.0 Then
            Return phase * 180.0 / Math.PI
        ElseIf v.Real < 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag >= 0.0 Then
            Return (phase * 180.0 / Math.PI) + 180.0
        ElseIf v.Real < 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag < 0.0 Then
            Return (phase * 180.0 / Math.PI) + 180.0
        ElseIf v.Real >= 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag < 0.0 Then
            Return (phase * 180.0 / Math.PI) + 360.0
        Else ' won't happen but I must have an ‘Return’ here
            Return Double.MaxValue
        End If
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function Add(v1 As ComplexNumber, v2 As ComplexNumber) As ComplexNumber
        Return New ComplexNumber(v1.Real + v2.Real, v1.Imag + v2.Imag, True)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function Subtract(v1 As ComplexNumber, v2 As ComplexNumber) As ComplexNumber
        Return New ComplexNumber(v1.Real - v2.Real, v1.Imag - v2.Imag, True)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function Multiply(v1 As ComplexNumber, v2 As ComplexNumber) As ComplexNumber
        Return New ComplexNumber(v1.Real * v2.Real - v1.Imag * v2.Imag,
                                 v1.Real * v2.Imag + v1.Imag * v2.Real,
                                 True)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function Divide(v1 As ComplexNumber, v2 As ComplexNumber) As ComplexNumber
        ' a+b*i   c-d*i     a*c+b*d -a*d*i +b*c*i
        ' ––––– * ––––– =  –––––––––––––––––––––––
        ' c+d*i   c-d*i        c^2 + d^2

        Dim realPart As Double = v1.Real * v2.Real + v1.Imag * v2.Imag

        Dim denominator As Double = Math.Pow(v2.Real, 2.0) + Math.Pow(v2.Imag, 2.0)

        Dim imaginaryPart As Double = -v1.Real * v2.Imag + v1.Imag * v2.Real

        Return New ComplexNumber(realPart / denominator, imaginaryPart / denominator, True)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function Conjugate(v1 As ComplexNumber) As ComplexNumber
        Return New ComplexNumber(v1.Real, -v1.Imag, True)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function Inverse(v1 As ComplexNumber) As ComplexNumber
        Dim conj As ComplexNumber = Conjugate(v1)
        Return New ComplexNumber(conj.Real / (Math.Pow(v1.Real, 2.0) + Math.Pow(v1.Imag, 2.0)),
                                 conj.Imag / (Math.Pow(v1.Real, 2.0) + Math.Pow(v1.Imag, 2.0)),
                                 True)
    End Function

    Private Sub SetOutputStrings(real As Double, imag As Double)
        Dim deu As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
        Dim plusOrMinus As String
        If imag >= 0.0 Then
            plusOrMinus = " + "
        Else
            plusOrMinus = " "
        End If
        Me.Output_Rectangular_form = $"{Math.Round(real, 3).ToString(deu)}{plusOrMinus}{Math.Round(imag, 3).ToString(deu)} * i"
        Dim cN As New ComplexNumber(real, imag, False)
        Dim absValue As Double = AbsoluteValue(cN)
        Dim angle As Double = AngleInRad(cN)
        Me.Output_Exponential_form = Math.Round(absValue, 3).ToString(deu) + $" * e^({Math.Round(angle, 3).ToString(deu)} * i)"
        Me.Output_Trigonometric_form = Math.Round(absValue, 3).ToString(deu) + $" * (cos({Math.Round(angle, 3).ToString(deu)}) + i * sin({Math.Round(angle, 3).ToString(deu)}))"
    End Sub

    Friend Shared Function AngleInRad(v As ComplexNumber) As Double
        Dim phase As Double = Math.Atan(v.Imag / v.Real)

        If v.Real >= 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag >= 0.0 Then
            Return phase
        ElseIf v.Real < 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag >= 0.0 Then
            Return phase + Math.PI
        ElseIf v.Real < 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag < 0.0 Then
            Return phase + Math.PI
        ElseIf v.Real >= 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag < 0.0 Then
            Return phase + 2.0 * Math.PI
        Else ' won't happen but I must have an ‘Return’ here
            Return Double.MaxValue
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

**FormMain.vb**

````
Public NotInheritable Class FormMain
    Private Real1, Imag1, Real2, Imag2 As Double
    Private Sub Textbox_r1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Textbox_r1.TextChanged
        Double.TryParse(Textbox_r1.Text, Real1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Textbox_i1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Textbox_i1.TextChanged
        Double.TryParse(Textbox_i1.Text, Imag1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Textbox_r2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Textbox_r2.TextChanged
        Double.TryParse(Textbox_r2.Text, Real2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Textbox_i2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Textbox_i2.TextChanged
        Double.TryParse(Textbox_i2.Text, Imag2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_absolute_value_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_absolute_value.Click
        Dim cN1 As New ComplexNumber(Me.Real1, Me.Imag1, True)
        Debug.WriteLine(ComplexNumber.AbsoluteValue(cN1))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_angle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_angle.Click
        Dim cN1 As New ComplexNumber(Me.Real1, Me.Imag1, True)
        Dim deu As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
        Debug.WriteLine(ComplexNumber.AngleInDegrees(cN1).ToString(deu) + " °")
        Debug.WriteLine(ComplexNumber.AngleInRad(cN1).ToString(deu))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_add.Click
        Dim cN1 As New ComplexNumber(Me.Real1, Me.Imag1, False)
        Dim cN2 As New ComplexNumber(Me.Real2, Me.Imag2, False)
        Dim result As ComplexNumber = ComplexNumber.Add(cN1, cN2)
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Output_Rectangular_form())
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Output_Exponential_form())
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Output_Trigonometric_form())
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_subtract_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_subtract.Click
        Dim cN1 As New ComplexNumber(Me.Real1, Me.Imag1, False)
        Dim cN2 As New ComplexNumber(Me.Real2, Me.Imag2, False)
        Dim result As ComplexNumber = ComplexNumber.Subtract(cN1, cN2)
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Output_Rectangular_form())
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Output_Exponential_form())
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_multiply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_multiply.Click
        Dim cN1 As New ComplexNumber(Me.Real1, Me.Imag1, False)
        Dim cN2 As New ComplexNumber(Me.Real2, Me.Imag2, False)
        Dim result As ComplexNumber = ComplexNumber.Multiply(cN1, cN2)
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Output_Rectangular_form())
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Output_Exponential_form())
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_divide_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_divide.Click
        Dim cN1 As New ComplexNumber(Me.Real1, Me.Imag1, False)
        Dim cN2 As New ComplexNumber(Me.Real2, Me.Imag2, False)
        Dim result As ComplexNumber = ComplexNumber.Divide(cN1, cN2)
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Output_Rectangular_form())
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Output_Exponential_form())
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_conj_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_conj.Click
        Dim cN1 As New ComplexNumber(Me.Real1, Me.Imag1, False)
        Dim result As ComplexNumber = ComplexNumber.Conjugate(cN1)
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Output_Rectangular_form())
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Output_Exponential_form())
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_inverse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_inverse.Click
        Dim cN1 As New ComplexNumber(Me.Real1, Me.Imag1, False)
        Dim result As ComplexNumber = ComplexNumber.Inverse(cN1)
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Output_Rectangular_form())
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Output_Exponential_form())
    End Sub
End Class
```
````

Answer (score 2):

First of all, although you only want to get rid of the boolean parameter, let us look at the code and see if we can improve it.

I would ask myself, do the methods `AbsoluteValue()` and `AngleInDegrees()` have to be `Friend Shared` functions? Performance should not be an issue because you call these methods each time you pass `True` in the constructor hence you could always calculate these values and provide them as a property of your class.

Because you assign values to `Imag` and `Real` inside the constructor you should make them `Readonly` properties.

Mixing languages while coding isn't that good. You should name stuff in just one language. So `Dim deu As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")` should be `Dim german As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")` or `germanCulture`. While coding you should always keep in mind that maybe **Sam the maintainer** won't speak German but mostly will speak English.

But let us stay at that `CultureInfo` object. Wouldn't it be better to have this as an optional parameter for the constructor?

About naming I would also like to mention that there exists [Naming guidlines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines?redirectedfrom=MSDN) which should be taken into account when naming stuff. Like e.g `Output_Trigonometric_form` should at least be `OutputTrigonometricForm` or imo better `TrigonometricForm` because `Output` doesn't add any value.

If you use one style you should keep to it. Having a look at `SetOutputStrings()` shows

```
Me.Output_Rectangular_form = $"{Math.Round(real, 3).ToString(deu)}{plusOrMinus}{Math.Round(imag, 3).ToString(deu)} * i"
```

and

```
 Me.Output_Exponential_form = Math.Round(absValue, 3).ToString(deu) + $" * e^({Math.Round(angle, 3).ToString(deu)} * i)"
```

using two different styles.

`AngleInDegrees()` and `AngleInRad()`

You each have a `Else` here with the comment

> won't happen but I must have an ‘Return’ here

which you could remove by changing the last `ElseIf` to an `Else`. But if you want to show the condition of the last evaluation it is imo ok to just throw an exception instead of returning some value.

Well, now I will show you both ways about your problem with the `setOutput` parameter. You could have an overloaded constructor in which you call the former constructor passing the desired value for `setOutput` like so

```
Friend Sub New(real As Double, imag As Double)
    Me.New(real, imag, False)
End Sub
```

But it really could be much simpler. Instead of passing a new `ComplexNumber` to `AbsoluteValue()` and `AngleInRad()` you could just pass `Me` as the argument.

But now let us take a look at the refactoring I suggested

```
Friend NotInheritable Class ComplexNumber

    Private plusOrMinus As String = " "
    Friend ReadOnly Property Radiant As Double
    Friend ReadOnly Property AbsoluteValue As Double
    Friend ReadOnly Property RectangularForm As String ' 3+4⋅i
    Friend ReadOnly Property TrigonometricForm As String ' r⋅(cos(ϕ)+i⋅sin(ϕ))
    Friend ReadOnly Property ExponentialForm As String ' r⋅e^(i⋅ϕ)
    Friend ReadOnly Property Real As Double
    Friend ReadOnly Property Imag As Double

    Friend Sub New(real As Double, imag As Double, Optional currentCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = Nothing)

        Me.Real = real
        Me.Imag = imag

        If currentCulture Is Nothing Then
            currentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
        End If

        If imag >= 0.0 Then
            plusOrMinus = " + "
        End If

        AbsoluteValue = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(real, 2.0) + Math.Pow(imag, 2.0))
        Radiant = AngleInRad(Me)

        RectangularForm = $"{Math.Round(real, 3).ToString(currentCulture)}{plusOrMinus}{Math.Round(imag, 3).ToString(currentCulture)} * i"
        ExponentialForm = $"{Math.Round(AbsoluteValue, 3).ToString(currentCulture)} * e^({Math.Round(Radiant, 3).ToString(currentCulture)} * i)"
        TrigonometricForm = $"{Math.Round(AbsoluteValue, 3).ToString(currentCulture)} * (cos({Math.Round(Radiant, 3).ToString(currentCulture)}) + i * sin({Math.Round(Radiant, 3).ToString(currentCulture)}))"

    End Sub

    Friend Shared Function AngleInDegrees(v As ComplexNumber) As Double
        Dim phase As Double = Math.Atan(v.Imag / v.Real)

        If v.Real >= 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag >= 0.0 Then
            Return phase * 180.0 / Math.PI
        ElseIf v.Real < 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag >= 0.0 Then
            Return (phase * 180.0 / Math.PI) + 180.0
        ElseIf v.Real < 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag < 0.0 Then
            Return (phase * 180.0 / Math.PI) + 180.0
        Else
            Return (phase * 180.0 / Math.PI) + 360.0
        End If
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function Add(v1 As ComplexNumber, v2 As ComplexNumber, Optional currentCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = Nothing) As ComplexNumber
        Return New ComplexNumber(v1.Real + v2.Real, v1.Imag + v2.Imag, currentCulture)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function Subtract(v1 As ComplexNumber, v2 As ComplexNumber, Optional currentCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = Nothing) As ComplexNumber
        Return New ComplexNumber(v1.Real - v2.Real, v1.Imag - v2.Imag, currentCulture)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function Multiply(v1 As ComplexNumber, v2 As ComplexNumber, Optional currentCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = Nothing) As ComplexNumber
        Return New ComplexNumber(v1.Real * v2.Real - v1.Imag * v2.Imag,
                                 v1.Real * v2.Imag + v1.Imag * v2.Real, currentCulture)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function Divide(v1 As ComplexNumber, v2 As ComplexNumber, Optional currentCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = Nothing) As ComplexNumber
        ' a+b*i   c-d*i     a*c+b*d -a*d*i +b*c*i
        ' ––––– * ––––– =  –––––––––––––––––––––––
        ' c+d*i   c-d*i        c^2 + d^2

        Dim realPart As Double = v1.Real * v2.Real + v1.Imag * v2.Imag

        Dim denominator As Double = Math.Pow(v2.Real, 2.0) + Math.Pow(v2.Imag, 2.0)

        Dim imaginaryPart As Double = -v1.Real * v2.Imag + v1.Imag * v2.Real

        Return New ComplexNumber(realPart / denominator, imaginaryPart / denominator, currentCulture)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function Conjugate(v1 As ComplexNumber, Optional currentCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = Nothing) As ComplexNumber
        Return New ComplexNumber(v1.Real, -v1.Imag, currentCulture)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function Inverse(v1 As ComplexNumber, Optional currentCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = Nothing) As ComplexNumber
        Dim conj As ComplexNumber = Conjugate(v1)
        Return New ComplexNumber(conj.Real / (Math.Pow(v1.Real, 2.0) + Math.Pow(v1.Imag, 2.0)),
                                 conj.Imag / (Math.Pow(v1.Real, 2.0) + Math.Pow(v1.Imag, 2.0)), currentCulture)
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function AngleInRad(v As ComplexNumber) As Double
        Dim phase As Double = Math.Atan(v.Imag / v.Real)

        If v.Real >= 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag >= 0.0 Then
            Return phase
        ElseIf v.Real < 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag >= 0.0 Then
            Return phase + Math.PI
        ElseIf v.Real < 0.0 AndAlso v.Imag < 0.0 Then
            Return phase + Math.PI
        Else
            Return phase + 2.0 * Math.PI
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Hi Heslacher, thanks for the solution and tips! Specially to pass ‘Me’ as argument – because of such improvements I post here :)
You are right, the strings can be properties, too. By the way: I had made the properties ‘Real’ and ‘Imag’ somewhat readonly, since I wrote ‘Private Set’. But your suggestion is better.